# Send push notifications from ActiveMQ

Tags: java, javascript, web-services, spring-boot

I am trying to figure out how to send push notifications back to the client in the following ActiveMQ scenario:

I have a `spring boot web application #1` deployed on tomcat on RHEL server. From the user interface (this consists of Javascript,jQuery,HTML,CSS), user clicks on a request files button, which calls
a RESTful webservice (a stored procedure gets called  and a unique identifier(number) is returned). I send this identifier as a message to ActiveMQ because the overall 
process could take 20-30 minutes.

With the help of this identifier I can check the status of the query from the database table.By status of the query I mean `COMPLETE, ERROR, STARTED, NOT YET STARTED`.I've
used this approach in my second spring boot web application as explained below.

I have another `spring boot web application #2` which is deployed on the RHEL server.This acts a a consumer and keep on listnening to the ActiveMQ queue.
With the help of the identifier from ActiveMQ ,as soon as this app sees the status as `COMPLETE`, it grabs records from 3 tables,convert the records into 3 csv files,
convert these 3 csv files into  a zip file and put it somewhere on the same server.

The zip file generated in the last step is not available immediately as soon as user clicks on the request files button from the `spring boot web app #1`.

I am wondering since I've two separate spring boot web applications, is it possible to send push notifications to the user interface of spring boot web application #1
so that user is  aware that their request is not yet completed and they need to wait? Is there something that ActiveMQ does to accomplish this?

Let me know if I can answer any questions relate to this.